# Changing text in DOM table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table that is automatically generated by an external piece of software (that I have to use and have no idea how it works).

I'm trying to change any item in the table with `datafld == "n0"` from something like this: `15HS01 15F24:HS632401.COUT` to just `15F24`.

I am attempting to use this code:

```
// Get all the tables in the document.
var doc_tables =  document.all.tags("TABLE");
for (ii = 0; ii < doc_tables.length; ii++ )
{
// Process each table.
FireZone( doc_tables(ii).id)
}


// Access the data table object ( use the dataFld string )
function FireZone( tableID )
{
// Get the 'specified' table object.
var table = eval("document.all." + tableID);

// Skip the header rows and get to the data rows in table 
var nHeadRows = table.rows.length - table.all.tags("TBODY").length;

// Iterate all rows in table....
if( table.rows.length > 0 )
{
    table
    for (i=nHeadRows; i < table.rows.length; i++ )
    {
        table(i).width = 1200;
        // Iterate all cells in each row - 

        for (j=0; j < table.rows(i).cells.length; j++)
        {

            // Locate cells by "dataFld" - interested in "n0" binding 
            // Get the Cell value
            for (k=0; k < table.rows(i).cells(j).children.length; k++)
            {
                if( table.rows(i).cells(j).children[k].dataFld == "n0" )
                {
                    var value = table.rows(i).cells(j).children[k].innerText;
                    if (value.search("15F") != -1)
                    {
                        table.rows(i).cells(j).children[k].innerText = value.substr(value.search("15F",5));
                    }
                }
            }
        } 
    }
}
}
```

But for some reason this code does not appear to do anything, nor does it throw an error however.

The HTML block corresponding to each row looks like this:

```
<TBODY>

<TR>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white" noWrap><SPAN dataFld=t0>9/16/2016 11:33:51 AM</SPAN></TD>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white"><SPAN dataFld=n0>15HS01 15F24:HS632401.COUT</SPAN></TD>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white" noWrap><SPAN dataFld=v0>0</SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY>
```

The script is definitely being run, so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps to start with, I found some javascript errors on your code

```js
// Get all the tables in the document.
var doc_tables =   document.querySelectorAll("TABLE");

for (ii = 0; ii < doc_tables.length; ii++ )
{
  console.log(doc_tables[ii].getAttribute("id"))
// Process each table.
FireZone( doc_tables[ii])

}


// Access the data table object ( use the dataFld string )
function FireZone( table )
{
// Get the 'specified' table object.
var table = eval(table);

var tds = table.querySelectorAll("td");
// Iterate all rows in table....
if( tds.length > 0 )
{
    for (i=0; i < tds.length; i++ )
    {
                    var value = tds[i].innerText;
                    
                    if (value.indexOf("15F") != -1)
                    {
                      var newValue = value.substr(value.indexOf("15F"),5);
                      console.log(newValue);
                        tds[i].innerText = value.substr(value.indexOf("15F",5));
                    }
    }
}
}
```

```css
td {color:#000}
```

```html
<table border="1">
<TBODY>

<TR>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white" noWrap><SPAN dataFld=t0>9/16/2016 11:33:51 AM</SPAN></TD>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white"><SPAN dataFld=n0>15HS01 15F24:HS632401.COUT</SPAN></TD>

<TD style="FONT-FAMILY: Georgia, serif; COLOR: white" noWrap><SPAN dataFld=v0>0</SPAN></TD></TR></TBODY>
  </table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I'm getting an error saying table doesn't contain method `querySelectorAll`